# How to nowcast in R with custom penalty function?

Tags: time-series, regression, midasr

I have some monthly data to nowcast GDP, but I want to increase accuracy by adding a penalty term. I am interesting in developing my own different from Ridge/Lasso? How can this be coded onto R?

I dont know where to start

Comment: Start by providing some dummy data and the code you have so far.